# Extjs combobox viewport

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs4

I am having trouble loading a combobox from the Viewport. For some reason the data is not getting rendered in the combobox. Could someone please help? I am using v 4.1 along with the mvc approach.

```
Ext.define('AM.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
layout: 'absolute',
items: [
    {
       xtype: 'combobox',
       fieldLabel: 'Stacker',
       region: 'center',
       store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
       fields: ['stk'],
       data: [
              {'stk': 'STK1'}, 
              {'stk': 'STK2'}
             ]
    }),
       queryMode: 'local',
       width: 200,
       x: 900,
       y: 70
    },
    {
        xtype: 'inventorylist',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        x: 25,
        y: 140
    },
    {
      xtype: 'stackerlist',  
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      x: 725,
      y:140
    }
```

]
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the displayField and valueField for the combo.

Comment: In this case, you'd just need a `displayField` since they are the same